# ArcMap - Spatial Join changed the values

Tags: arcmap, spatial-join

I just run spatial join on two big tables I have.
for some reason, one of the columns has changed its values-
 for example, on the original input layer I had this value. :

```
72145367277699000
```

the datatype of this is 'real' , column ID_Agri
[image: field ID_Agri]

and on the output join layer it changed to:

```
72145400000000000
```

[image]
Does anyone know what makes this difference.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the datatype of the column.  It looks like a 32-bit float (single), which can only store 6-7 significant digits.

Comment: Datatype is a property of every field.

Comment: It is not safe to store ID values in floating-point representation, especially those whose formatted width exceeds the theoretical maximum of double precision, much less single precison.

Comment: so how can I solve it? how can I change the way it is stored? is that the reason it happens?

Comment: Copying the IDs into text field would work. The values and data type will not change in the Spatial Join.